# Same abbreviation in acronym list and symbol list

Tags: symbols, glossaries, acronyms

I want to include an acronym EPS and a symbol EPS in my acronym and symbol list, respectively. I try to do it as follows:

```
\usepackage[acronym,automake,toc,shortcuts,symbols]{glossaries-extra}
\makeglossaries
\newacronym{EPS}{EPS}{Earnings per Share}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={Earnings Per Share}]{EPS}{\ensuremath{EPS}}
```

However, it says that the acronym has already been defined when the compiling process reaches the last line. Is there a way to circumvent this and include the same abbreviation in both lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

both the `newacronym` and the `glsxtrnewsymbol` in fact define a new glossary entry. You cannot have two entries with the same label.

If I understand your question correctly you want to have an entry that is both an acronym and a symbol. You want that entry to appear in both the acronym list and the symbol list.

The simple solution would be to define them separately: The acronym would be:

```
\newacronym{EPSac}{EPS}{Earnings per Share}
```

And the symbol would be

```
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={Earnings Per Share}]{EPSsym}{\ensuremath{EPS}}
```

Or you could define them as one and link them thus:

```
\newglossaryentry{EPSsymb} {
  name={\ensuremath{EPS}},
  description={Earnings Per Share},
}
\newacronym[see={[Glossary:]{EPSsymb}}]{EPS}{EPS}{Earnings Per Share\glsadd{EPSsym}}
```

You could use this to define a dual entry, [see this page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Glossary#Dual_entries_with_reference_to_a_glossary_entry_from_an_acronym)